# How to override Visual Studio Code source

Tags: visual-studio-code, overriding, extend, vscode-extensions

I want to be able to extend/override some of the [VS Code source](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) in my extension, but I'm not sure how to do so. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extensions (as the name says) can extend the functionality of the host application (here vscode), but they are separate code parts which have no access to the host application code and structures (except those particularly exported for use by extensions).

If you want to modify vscode source code then clone the repo, change the code and build your own vscode application.